# Typescript: generic type restriction on return value of keyof

Tags: typescript

Upgrading to TypeScript 3.5 has caused some code of mine to no longer compile. I think this is because of a breaking change: [Generic type parameters are implicitly constrained to unknown](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#generic-type-parameters-are-implicitly-constrained-to-unknown). I'm trying to find the best way to fix the code now.

**TL;DR**: how do I declare a generic function with types `T` and `K extends keyof T`, but where `T[K]` must be a string.

**Longer version**: I want to convert an array of objects to a single object which has all the values in the array, keyed on some property of the objects. For example:

```
type Person = { id: string, firstName: string, lastName: string, age: number}

const array: Person[] = [
    {id: "a", firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith", age: 27},
    {id: "b", firstName: "Bill", lastName: "Brown", age: 53}
]

const obj = convertArrayToObject(array, "id")
```

The result of this would be that `obj` would have this structure:

```
{ 
    a: {id: "a", firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith", age: 27},
    b: {id: "b", firstName: "Bill", lastName: "Brown", age: 53}
}
```

I had this function to do this:

```
type ItemsMap<T> = { [key: string]: T }

function convertArrayToObject<T>(array: Array<T>, indexKey: keyof T): ItemsMap<T> {
    return array.reduce((accumulator: ItemsMap<T>, current: T) => {
        const keyObj = current[indexKey]
        const key = (typeof keyObj === "string") ? keyObj : keyObj.toString()
        accumulator[key] = current
        return accumulator
    }, {})
}
```

Since upgrading to TypeScript 3.5, the error is on the call to `toString`: `Property toString does not exist on type T[keyof T]`.

I can understand the problem: since that breaking change in TypeScript 3.5 the return value of `current[indexKey]` is now `unknown` rather than an object, so `toString` can't be called on it. But how do I get round this?

Ideally what I'd like to do is put a generic constraint on the type of the `indexKey` parameter such that you can only pass in a key whose return value is itself a string. Here's what I've managed to get so far (though I'm not sure if it's the best approach):

First, I declare a type which is used to find all properties of a given type, `TObj`, which return a given type of result, `TResult`:

```
type PropertiesOfType<TObj, TResult> =
    { [K in keyof TObj]: TObj[K] extends TResult ? K : never }[keyof TObj]
```

So for example I could now get all the string properties of `Person`:

```
type PersonStringProps = PropertiesOfType<Person, string> // "firstName" | "lastName" | "id"
```

And now I can declare the function as follows:

```
function convertArrayToObject<T, K extends PropertiesOfType<T, string>>(
    array: Array<T>, indexKey: K): ItemsMap<T> { ...
```

I can now only call the function with properties that return string, for exampe:

```
convertArrayToObject(array, "id") // Compiles, which is correct
convertArrayToObject(array, "age") // Doesn't compile, which is correct
```

However, in the function body, I still can't seem to use the passed in `keyof T` and have the compiler know that the value is returned is a string:

```
return array.reduce((accumulator: ItemsMap<T>, current: T) => {
    const key: string = current[indexKey]
```

This doesn't compile: `Type T[K] is not assignable to type string`. I can get round this by casting:

```
const key: string = current[indexKey] as unknown as string
```

And I guess that's safe as I know that `current[IndexKey]` is a string. But it still doesn't seem quite right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily fix this by changing `keyObj.toString()` call to `String(keyObj)` which will internally call `.toString()` on whatever you pass it so behavior will stay the same except that it won't blow up on `undefined` and `null`. In fact you can replace the whole line:

```
const key = (typeof keyObj === "string") ? keyObj : keyObj.toString()
```

with

```
const key = String(keyObj)
```

because if it is a string it will just not do anything.

**UPDATE:**

You almost had the correct type safe solution, you just need an extra constraint on `T`:

```
function convertArrayToObject<
  T extends { [Key in K]: string }, // This is required for the reduce to work
  K extends PropertiesOfType<T, string>
>(array: Array<T>, indexKey: K): ItemsMap<T> {
  return array.reduce((accumulator: ItemsMap<T>, current: T) => {
    accumulator[current[indexKey]] = current
    return accumulator
  }, {})
}
```

Comment: You're right, thanks. That would get back to the behaviour before the upgrade to TS 3.5. Ideally though I'd like to restrict the function so that you can only call it passing in a `keyof T` whose return value is a string. I'll keep the question open for a bit to see if anyone else has any ideas.

Comment: @YoniGibbs I've updated my answer with a type safe solution as well

Comment: Ah, perfect, thanks very much. That extra constraint on `T` was indeed what was missing. With that in place, the cast is no longer required. Great!